# How do I install CUDA 10.0 on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: nvidia, 18.10, cuda

I am trying to use the tensorflow-gpu, however tensorflow only supports CUDA 10.0 and not 10.1. It seems that only CUDA 10.1 is available from the apt repository provided by nvidia. I have searched in vain for a way to install CUDA 10.0 on my Ubuntu 18.10. It does seems possible on Ubuntu 18.04.

**How do I install CUDA 10.0 on Ubuntu 18.10?**

Comment: Try getting CUDA 10 at https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

Answer (score 1):

According to [CUDA 10 documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.0/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) Ubuntu 18.04 is supported only (different Kernel version).